# ¿Como selecionar un elemento del DOM por su id en ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript, ionic2

Tengo un elemento en el `DOM` que es el siguiente:

```
<input type="text" id="miElemento" class="miElemento">
<ion-item class="input_float">
    <ion-label floating >Nombre:</ion-label>
    <ion-input class="x" id="nombre" #nombre name="nombre" type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombre" 
        (click)=" placeholderNombre=' Ej: Carlos Alberto Rodriguez Gacha';" 
        (blur)=" placeholderNombre=''" placeholder="{{placeholderNombre}}">
    </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

y en mi archivo ts intento selecionarlo atravez de metodo `getElementById()` de la forma siguiente:

```
console.log("resultado por id:",document.getElementById("miElemento"));
console.log("resultado por class:",document.getElementsByClassName("miElemento"));
```

El resultado por consola es el el siguiente:

```
resultado por id: null
resultado por class: []length: 1 
                      miinput: div#nombre.miinput
                            0: div#nombre.miinput
                    __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

¿Por que no lo logro con el metodo `getElementById()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular no puede tomar elementos HTML directamente por lo que necesita especificar el tipo de elemento vinculado.

Puedes usar [@ViewChild](https://pablolazaro.github.io/2016/10/13/Angular-2-Controlando-componentes-hijos-con-ViewChild-y-ViewChildren/):

> `@ViewChild` - es utilizado sobre una propiedad de la clase que representa a un componente, permite obtener las instancias de elementos nativos, directivas y componentes que estén en el template del mismo.

**1.** Agregamos primero el decorador `#miElemento`:

```
<div id="miElemento" #miElemento class="miElemento"> mi elemento </div>
```

**2.** en el componente agregamos la correspondencia:

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

...

export class ExamplePage
{
   @ViewChild( 'miElemento' ) miElemento: ElementRef;

   constructor() {}       

   ngAfterViewInit() {

       console.log( this.miElemento); // ElementRef {nativeElement: div#miElemento.miElemento}
       console.log( this.miElemento.nativeElement.id ); // "miElemento"
   }

...
```

<kbd>[Ver Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/Y4kB6oxiDEQwlDKL30qD/)</kbd>

Comment: Bien, Gracias, es en parte lo que necesito. pero aun no logro lo que quiero,
Realmente lo que necesito es que el elemento sea un input, y después de seleccionarlo quiero darle foco atravez del metodo focus(); de un input, y utilizo lo siguiente: this.miElemento.nativeElement.focus(); ahi pasa dos cosas en mi aplicacion el input no queda enfocado, pero lo probe en su demo y ahi si funciona, ¿por que pasa esto?

Comment: @DanielEnriqueRodriguezCaste - Haz usado los imports `{ ... ElementRef, ViewChild  ... }` ? Haz declarado el decorador en el elemento `#miElemento` ? Como y donde implementas el método `focus` ?...

Comment: tal cual, ngAfterViewInit() { var miElemento = this.miElemento.nativeElement;  
miElemento.focus();
   }

Comment: @DanielEnriqueRodriguezCaste - Podrías hacer una demo con [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU?p=info) con tu código? Así te podría ayudar...